# Python Request - result length limited?

Tags: python, json

I'm downloading JSON file in Python3 with Requests:

```
data = requests.get(addr).text
```

But some characters at end sometimes got cutted. For example: only 4570 of 4630 characters was in string.What is reason of this behaviour? Spamming F5 in browser does not reproduce problem, only in script.

**EDIT:**
Ok, I see that sometimes server responding HTTP304 (Not changed) and missing `Content-Length` header. Any solution possible to read all without this header?

Comment: There is none. At least not reliable. If the problem is on the server's side then there's not much you can do.

Comment: Can't you solve it by checking the `Response.status_code` or possibly `Response.ok` and retry/keep previous if it is not a 200-code?

Comment: @deinonychusaur - yep, I'm doing it now